# firebase cloud schedule function not printing anything out on console

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I asked this question a few hours ago. The question was only partially answered and then closed, so I think it is reasonable to post it again.

**Question**
I created a firebase cloud function that runs every minute to update some data in cloud firestore. The logic of the code is right, as I have tested in at frontend. However, after I deployed the function, nothing was logged on the firebase console except for the 2 notification messages I got upon deployment. Besides, there was no error logged on the console either. Thanks to the answer given by @Doug Stevenson, I now know that schedule functions are not currently supported by firebase emulators so I cannot test the function using emulators. I am confused about where I got the code wrong.

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./ServiceAccountKey.json')
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
})

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minute').onRun((context) => {
    var rooms = [];
    var open;
    console.log("start");
    const db = admin.firestore();
    db.collection("rooms").get().
    then((query) => {

        console.log(query.docs);
        ......
    })
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been better if you had provided some Cloud Functions logs, in order to analyze what's happening. But, from your code, we can see that there are two potential problems in your Cloud Function:

1. `firebase-admin` shall normally be initialized without any parameters within the Cloud Functions runtime. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?authuser=0#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin
2. You don't return the Promise returned by the asynchronous `get()` method, which is key within a scheduled Cloud Function (as well as within all background triggered ones). See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

So, the following should do the trick:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1 minute').onRun((context) => {
    var rooms = [];
    var open;
    console.log("start");
    const db = admin.firestore();
    return db.collection("rooms").get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {

            console.log(querySnapshot.docs);
            //......
            return null;  // Or a promise returned by another async method call
        })
});
```

Comment: wow it does work! But why adding the service account credentials did not work? I was following the tutorial provided by firebase in which the the person added the service account credentials as the parameter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z87OZtIYC_0

Comment: "Why adding the service account credentials did not work" => because it is not the way to initialize an admin app instance in a Cloud Function. The tutorial you refer to is mainly for implementing Node.js code in a server and you initialize the admin app instance for a server. At 3min07sec in the video, Jen Person explains that for Cloud Functions there is a different way (`admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);`).

Comment: **HOWEVER**, even if you would have used this way it would have not worked, because, since then (and since Version 1.0.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions) it has changed. This is explained in the doc I referred to in my answer. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?authuser=0#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Renaud! I got a weird problem for this function after running it successfully for a whole day (while I got "function returned undefined" error, the function printed out staff and modified firestore data as expected) before I added a few changes to the code that by no means can possible stop it from working but they did! The error I got was "memory-limit-exceeded." I made a post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63441958/firebase-cloud-function-error-memory-limit-exceeded-function-invocation-was-in?noredirect=1#comment112183764_63441958. Could you check it out?