# firebase cloud function error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My scheduled cloud function reads from a firestore collection that has less than 1 MB of data every 2 minutes and only has "functions" and "admin" as global variables, but it got the memory-limit-exceeded error. I am wondering (1) what caused the problem and (2) how to clear the memory.

**Some clues**

1. Initially, I did not have `return true` at the end of the cloud function, and there was only a "Functions returned undefined" error. However, I did not get the "memory-limit-exceeded" error, and the function worked as expected. After I added 2 fields in the firestore update method (near the end of the function), the "memory-limit-exceeded" error was reported and the function stopped working.
2. Right now only "start" was printed on console followed by "memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted." and the code did not enter the callback of get().

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  
    var rooms = [];
    var open;
    console.log("start");
    const db = admin.firestore();
    return db.collection("rooms").get().
    then((query) => {

        console.log(query.docs);
        rooms = query.docs;
        for (var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {

            open = rooms[i].data().open;
            const temp = rooms[i].data();
            const roomid = rooms[i].id;
            console.log(temp);
            console.log(roomid);
            console.log(typeof temp);
            if (temp.hasOwnProperty('schedule')) {

           
            const schedule = temp.schedule;
            const scheduleDuplicate = schedule;
            console.log(schedule);

            //The nested while loops below basically check whether a scheduled virtual room should be displayed by comparing current time with the scheduled time periods
            var j = 0;
            var check = false;
            while (j < schedule.length && check === false) {

                const slots = schedule[j].slots;
                var z = 0;

               
                while (z < slots.length && check === false) {
                  const array = slots[z].array;
                  var k = 0;
  
                
                  while (k < array.length && check === false) {
                    

                      const currentDate = new Date().toUTCString();
                      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                      const startTime = new Date(array[k].startTime).getTime();
                      const endTime = new Date(array[k].endTime).getTime();
                      
                      console.log(array[k].startTime, startTime);
                      console.log(array[k].endTime, endTime);
                      console.log(currentDate, currentTime);
                      if (currentTime > endTime) {
                        console.log("too late");
                          array.splice(k, 1);
                      }
                      else if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime) {
                        console.log("between");
                          check = true;
                          break;
                      }
                      else if (currentTime < startTime) {
                        console.log("too early");
                          break;
                      }
                  }

                  console.log(array);

                  if (array.length === 0) {
                    slots.splice(z, 1);
                  }
                  else slots[z].array = array;
                }

                console.log(slots);

                if (slots.length === 0) {
                    schedule.splice(j, 1);
                }
                else schedule[j].slots = slots; 
            }
            console.log(schedule);
            return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
                return transaction.get(db.collection("rooms").doc(roomid))
                .then((doc) => {
                  if (doc.exists) {
                    transaction.update(db.collection("rooms").doc(roomid), {schedule: schedule});
                    return "dummy";
                  }
                })
            })
            .then((dummy) => {
                if (check === false && open === true) {
                  console.log("close the room");
                    db.collection("rooms").doc(roomid).update({
                        open: false
                        
                    })
                    .then((dummy) => {
                      return true;
                    })
                }
                else if (check === true && open === false) {
                    console.log("open the room");
                    db.collection("rooms").doc(roomid).update({
                        //Added "notifications" and "participants" fields to be updated, deployed the function again, and the "memory-limit-exceeded" error" occuered.
                        notifications: 0,
                        participants: [],
                        open: true
                    })
                    .then((dummy) => {
                      return true;
                    })
                }
                return true;
            })
      
        }
        }
        return true;
    })
    .then((dummy) => {
    return true;
    })
    
})
```

Comment: First thing is that your function should return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.  Right now, you are not waiting for anything to complete and immediately returning true. This could cause all kinds of other problems downstream.

Comment: you're right. Just edited my code but it still got the "functions return undefined" and "memory-limit-exceeded" errors.

Comment: Your code still does not return a promise from the top level.

Comment: Hi Doug can you check my updated clue #1? I added "return" before the ```db.collection("rooms").get()``` async call and have got rid of the "Function returned undefined" error. However, the "memory-limit-exceeded" error is still there.

Comment: Before I added the 2 fields in the update method, the function worked as expected even with the "function returned undefined" error.

Comment: Turns out you have a bunch of other promises that you're ignoring throughout your code.  All Firestore operations return a promise.

Comment: So the only operations that I did not add promises to were the 2 update() methods at the end. After adding the promises (I updated the code in the post), I still got the same error. Also, the function worked fine initially even when I did not add those promises, and after adding the 2 fields to be updated and redeployment today I got the memory-limit-exceeded error suddenly. Could it be something else that caused the problem?